# Char vector is modified on copying character in C++

Tags: c++11

Following is my submission for

https://leetcode.com/problems/letter-combinations-of-a-phone-number

However I see very weird behavior on lines

```
char c = map1[s[i]][j];
t.replace(i,1,1,c);
```

The vector map1[s[i]] is changing size on execution of above line in the code below. How can character c be copied by value rather than reference. If I remove reference for string in function argument (meaning no &) everything works fine but it won't be the right way, since copying string by value is costly.

```
class Solution {
public:
    string s;
    vector<string> res;
    unordered_map<char, vector<char>> map1;
    void letterCombinations(string &t, int i){
        char c;
        if(s.size()==0)
            return;
        if(i==s.size())
            res.push_back(t);
        else{
            for(int j=0;j<map1[s[i]].size();j++){
                //cout<<"Starting:"<<map1[s[i]].size()<<endl;
                char c = map1[s[i]][j];
                t.replace(i,1,1,c);
                letterCombinations(t, i+1);
                //cout<<"Return:"<<map1[s[i]].size()<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        stringstream t;
        map1['1'] = vector<char>{};
        map1['0'] = vector<char>{};
        map1['2'] = vector<char>{'a','b','c'};
        map1['3'] = vector<char>{'d','e','f'};
        map1['4'] = vector<char>{'g','h','i'};
        map1['5'] = vector<char>{'j','k','l'};
        map1['6'] = vector<char>{'m','n','o'};
        map1['7'] = vector<char>{'p','q','r','s'};
        map1['8'] = vector<char>{'t','u','v'};
        map1['9'] = vector<char>{'w','x','y','z'};

        s=digits;
        letterCombinations(s,0);
        return res;
    }

};
```

Comment: "is changing size on execution" How do you know? Post your observations, not conclusions.

Comment: I don't really understand what your code is doing, but be aware that `s` and `t` are one and the same; both denote the same `string` object. So `t.replace(i,1,1,c);` also changes `s[i]`; and therefore, `map1[s[i]]` looks at different map entries before and after - quite possibly with different sizes.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks Igor. Your great observation helped me solve and find the bug!